# missing right parenthesis in create table

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I searched the forum but didn't find the right answer sorry if I double post
I want to create this Table

```
create table HUB_SHIFT_REPORT
(
  Da_te timestamp(8) not null
, Week_Day varchar2(10) not null constraint cnstrnt_day check (Week_Day in('Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'))
, Shift varchar2(10) not null constraint cnstrnt_shift check (Shift in('Morning','Evening','Night'))
, Handled_by varchar2(60) not null constraint cnstrnt_handled check (Handled_by in('Artyom','Natan','Asaph','Yaniv','Fadi','AdiG','AdiF','Paul','Benjamin','Matan','Yosef'))
, Incident_Number number(10) not null PRIMARY KEY
, Centreon_Duration varchar2(10) not null
, Time_received varchar2(10) not null
, Time_restored varchar2(10) not null
, Time_closed varchar2(10) not null
, Product varchar2(60) not null constraint cnstrnt_product check (Product in ('Primo','MetaLib','SFX','bX','Primo Central','USTAT','Alma','Aleph','voayger','Marcit','ARC','Verde','Rosetta','Digitool','MetaLib+','NUUL','Not product related'))
, Service_name varchar2(400) not null
, Data_Center varchar2(10) constraint cnstrnt_dc check (Data_Center in ('DC01','DC02','DC03','DC04','DC05','Amazon','NULL'))
, HOST VARCHAR2(40) 
, GUEST VARCHAR2(40) 
, Alert_Name varchar2(400) not null
, Alert_Status varchar2(40) cnstrnt_status check (Alert_Status in ('CRITICAL','WARNING','UNKNOWN','DOWN','NULL'))
, Affected_Customers varchar2(400) not null
, Is_Escalated varchar2(10) default ('No') cnstrnt_yes check (Is_Escalated in('Yes','No'))
, Escalated_at varchar2(10) default ('NULL') 
, Escalated_to varchar2(100) default ('NULL')
, Open_Action_items varchar2(400) default ('NULL')
, Time_Resolved varchar2(10) default ('NULL')
, Related_alerts varchar2(50) default ('NULL')
, Related_critical_alert_host varchar2(100) default ('NULL')
, Is_Reported varchar2(10) default ('No') cnstrnt_yes check (Is_Reported in('Yes','No'))
, Alert_Accuracy varchar2(10) default ('Real alert') not null cnstrnt_alert check (Alert_Accuracy in ('Real alert','False Positive'))
, SI_number varchar2(10) default ('NULL')
, Customer_Type varchar2(15) default ('Direct') not null cnstrnt_type check (Customer_Type in ('Total Care','Direct','SaaS','Local'))
, Resolved varchar2(20) default ('No') cnstrnt_yes2 check (Resloved in('Yes','No','Cleared Itself'))
, in_ERD varchar2(10) default ('Yes') cnstrnt_yes check (In_ERD in('Yes','No'))
, In_XLS varchar2(10) default ('Yes') cnstrnt_yes check (In_XLS in('Yes','No')) 
, Actions_Taken varchar2(10) default ('No') cnstrnt_yes check (Actions_Taken in('Yes','No'))
, Notes varchar2(800)
, Root_cause varchar2(200) not null
, Can_be_prevented varchar2(10) default ('No') cnstrnt_yes check (Can_be_prevented in('Yes','No'))
, log varchar2(1800)
)
```

But I get

> Error at Command Line:14 Column:27 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00907:
>   missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I count the right and left paranthesis and get 83 in both cases
Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to default an optional column to 'NULL' (which is a four-character string)?

Comment: This is a trivial syntax error. Please go through your code more closely instead of posting it on SO.  The compiler even gives you the line to look at - `line 14`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change...
  - `, Data_Center varchar2(10) cnstrnt_dc check`

To...
  - `, Data_Center varchar2(10) constraint cnstrnt_dc check`

***NOTE:*** You seem to have the `constraint` keyword missing in several places.

Comment: @sdblepas: You're also using the same constraint name (`cnstrnt_yes`) more than once, and you have a typo (`Resloved`) in your script. If this answer solved your problem, make sure to accept it.

Comment: Ok I had also other errors I used the same name for one constraint several times :)

Comment: @PeterLang I just saw you comment :) Thx